# how can i make maven to notify once my build is successful or failure by some beep sound or something?

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven to build my project through command line.

Building a project often takes lot of time and I end up regularly looking into the screen to check whether my build is successful or not. So my question is, does maven provide any option to notify user on a build completion or failure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `mvn -e clean install & start target` and it will open a window once build is complete

Comment: what about failure cases and where can I read about more such options ?

Comment: this is a workaround. using this you need to manually check what was the result. Even you can use any path after `start` like "/play/media/file.mp3". this does not take care of success/failure, it just waits for first command to complete no matter what the outcome was..